# Is it possible to install two SSD M2 drives using only 1 SATA port?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, raid, sata

I have a six years old Toshiba laptop computer. It has traditional mechanical hard drive with SATA3 interface. It has no M2 SSD interface.

I am wondering if it is possible to install 2 SSD M2 using the only one SATA3 it has by using some kind of adapter that accepts two M2 SSD, and configure it as a RAID, I mean, two M2 SSD behaving as only 1 SSD.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Can you provide more info about your laptop model or specifications, please

Comment: Are those SSDs made for SATA or NVMe?

Comment: @TamalesRancheros Toshiba SATELLITE P50-B-10V model PSPNUE-00W00JCE. Specs here: https://emea.dynabook.com/discontinued-products/satellite-p50-b-10v/

Comment: @user1686 I have not bought anything yet. I was thinking to buy some kind of SATA raid enclosure supporting two M2 SSD. Anyway I have not found anything for laptops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; what an excellent idea!

If your laptop will accept a 7mm tall, 2.5" wide drive enclosure into a SATA-III drive bay, there is such a device from StarTech, their https://www.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/m2-sata-adapter~S322M225R which specifically says it's for RAID use and accepts SATA-III M.2 drives. It does not take NVMe drives, so be careful when acquiring the M.2 drives to specify SATA-III, not NVMe.

However, not all laptops use a 2.5" internal drive; some use a 1.8", so please verify that by reviewing the specs for your particular model.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I shall get one as well.